# PHP application - mocking / speeding up MySQL requests for local environment?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, localhost

I'm not a back-end developer and I don't know much about devops, but I will try.

I've been working with Docker containers as a front-end developer with many applications, mostly PHP-based, Laravel, Phalcon, Symphony, you name it.

One things that has been bugging me for years now is the performance of local environment, especially when it comes to (any?) databases - it doesn't matter if I'm using remote MySQL database on a server or setup an MySQL container on localhost - requests are always so super slow compared to production, in worst cases reloading some pages took tens of seconds if not minutes.

I'm wondering whether is it possible for a simple front-end dev to setup mocked MySQL database somehow, like an object that will pretend to be my MySQL database with all the structure and data but much faster? 99% of the time I do not want to update records in my bases anyway, so something read-only would be totally sufficient. Of course I want this to work as a normal db, it means it can receive and send data.

I won't lie I had the same problem with almost every single startup I worked on (excepting... WordPress :P), not only in PHP but also in other languages, I'm using top-tier MacBook so it's performance is still far away from real web servers but I think it should be sufficient.

Thanks for any hints :)

Comment: My local MySQL has always been quite performant. Figure out why it's so slow - not enough RAM? CPU? Different indexes?

Comment: You're not being consistent in your demands: "something read-only would be totally sufficient", and then: "I want this to work as a normal db, it means it can receive and send data." The first thing that comes to my mind is SQLite in memory, but I'm sure you'll find any solution like that problematic, because you basically want it to work exactly as the existing database. The only thing that does that is the existing database.

Comment: Probably you just have a default mysql config, `my.conf` with no memory allowed for MySql indexes.  A local test machine may have severe memory restrictions compared to a server, My PC only has two CPU's (not cores/ 2x i5 duo cores) and 18GB of DDR4 (I know poor me) but consider my Live server which has 24 cores, and 54GB or ram.

Comment: If you're working with frameworks, the dev environment may be slower than the prod environment because it's configured to reprocess everything for each request rather than loading stuff from cache, and may have additional profiling/logging/etc. happening that won't happen in prod. The actual queries may not be much slower.